# Spring boot Schedule payment on several months and specific date

Tags: java, spring, cron, schedule

It is new to me to schedule tasks in Spring boot application. I have read several posts about it but could not manage to put them together.
In my case customer sets his payment dateFrom to some date, his payment dateTo to some date in future and a payment day of month for example every 25th of month.
So if I set my dates like this 01-04-2018 - 30-08-2018 and pay day every 25th, my scheduled task should be executed every 25th of every month, like this 25-04, 25-05, 25-06, 25-07 and 25-08. I will post my entity model below. I could not write any working service for this. Please help.

```
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
@Column(name = "amount")
private BigDecimal amount;
@Column(name = "outcome")
private Boolean outcome;
@Column(name = "currency")
@Convert(converter = CurrencyConverter.class)
private Currency currency;
@Column(name = "comment")
private String comment;
@Column(name = "dimension")
@Convert(converter = DimensionConverter.class)
private Dimension dimension;
@Column(name = "type_id")
@Convert(converter = ExpenseTypeConverter.class)
private ExpenseType expenseType;


@Column(name = "finished_payment", nullable = true)
private Boolean finishedExpense;


@Column(name = "period_from", nullable = true)
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd-MM-yyyy")
private Date periodFrom;
@Column(name = "period_to", nullable = true)
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd-MM-yyyy")
private Date periodTo;
@Column(name = "pay_day", nullable = true)
private int payDay;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **@EnableScheduing** in Spring Boot..

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 300000)
//300000=5 mins.
public void startQuery(){
    try{
        /Schedule something here
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

you can also use **Cron** expression in place of **fixedDelay** . 
For your use case you should use **Quartz+Spring boot** . Read docs here.. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-quartz.html